# ProgressBar как работает?

Tags: c#

Расскажите как работает, как запустить. К примеру есть две формы. Сначала появляется вторая, на ней ProgressBar. Он проходит, закрывается вторая форма и появляется родительская, и там мы уже выполняем какие либо действия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кладешь на форму компонент, устанавливаешь ему [Minimum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.minimum.aspx) и [Maximum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum.aspx), устанавливаешь [Step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.step.aspx), производишь некие действия, скажем, в цикле и после каждого действия вызываешь [PerformStep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.performstep.aspx), в итоге закрываешь форму ну или делаешь что-то еще (по необходимости), на что хватит фантазии.

P.S. по сылкам есть примеры кода, все интуитивно понятно

Comment: Спасибо, буду читать и пробовать.

Comment: Заходи почаще на MSDN, многие вопросы там достаточно подробно излагаются

Comment: Я там часто бываю, но трудно найти нормальное объяснение проблемы, они какие-то сложные примеры там дают, а я в этом деле ещё новичок.

Comment: Ну ничего, придет со временем :)

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx

После описания есть пример работы